# SAS Macro for updating column based on occurrence of a substring

Tags: automation, sas, sas-macro

my code currently uses the tranwrd function in order to update a column based on the occurrence of a specified substring.  I would like to have a macro that achieves this in order to automate this process since my data set is quite large. Any help would be appreciated. My code is below.

```
data subject_data;
  infile datalines;
  input SUBID;
datalines;                                         /*OUTPUT*/

H7891133 1029 10151024               H7891133 1029 14451024
H7891133 1029 10241005               H7891133 1029 15101005
H7891133 1029 10241019               H7891133 1029 15101019
;
run;

Data update_sub ;
        Set subject_data;
        SUBID_char = put(SUBID, 22.) ;
        /*drop SUBID ;
        rename SUBID_char=SUBID ; */

        if substr(SUBID_char,15,8)='10151024' then do 
        SUBID_char=tranwrd(SUBID_char, "10151024", "14451024");
        put SUBID_char;
        end;

        if substr(SUBID_char,15,8)='10241005' then do 
        SUBID_char=tranwrd(SUBID_char, "10241005", "15101005");
        put SUBID_char;
        end;

        if substr(SUBID_char,15,8)='10241019' then do 
        SUBID_char=tranwrd(SUBID_char, "10241019", "15101019");
        put SUBID_char;
        end;
        
run;
```

Comment: SAS `SUBSTR` parameters are `(string, position, length)`. You appear to be coding with an incorrect assumption they are `(string, start-position, end-position)`

Comment: Your example shows 3 values being replaced.  How many values to you expect to have to replace?  What is the source of  this mapping from old value to new value?

Comment: @tom Thank you for your reply. I have 20 values that need to be replaced in a column from a data set with several thousand rows. The source of the mapping is from an external list that is not apart of the data set. Having a macro would allow me to just call it by entering the old and new values into the parameter of the macro.

Comment: @Richard Thank you for your reply. I have updated the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to maintain a data set of mapping values.  The $8 substring subject to change can be the index of a hash.  No need for macro.

Example:

```
data sub_id_maps;
  input from $ to $; datalines;
10151024 14451024
10241005 15101005
10241019 15101019
;

data have;
  input id $char30.; datalines;
H7891133 1029 10151024
H7891133 1029 10241005
H7891133 1029 10241019
H7891133 1029 11111111
H7891133 1029 22222222
H7891133 1029 33333333
;

data want;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    if 0 then set sub_id_maps; * prep pdv with 'from' and 'to' variables;
    declare hash maps(dataset:'sub_id_maps');
    maps.defineKey('from');
    maps.defineData('to');
    maps.defineDone();
    drop from to;
  end;

  set have;

  if maps.find(key:substr(id,15,8)) = 0 then 
    substr(id,15,8) = to;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How could I use this approach for updating 20 values in a column of a data set with several thousand rows?  Would you also happen to have a macro-based approach?

Comment: The 20 values to be updated is the `sub_id_maps` dataset in the answer. The `have` dataset in the answer is the one that can have several thousands (or millions) of observations.

Comment: At this point the problem does not exhibit any need for any macro. `sub_id_maps` is a *parameter* or *control* data set that affects the domain of values on which the `want` step operates.  If your `have` data set has 20 columns (variables) of ids, say `id1` to `id20`, then the `want` step code should be updated to use an array.

Comment: @Richard when I run this code, the data set only contains the number of rows equivalent to the number of mappings specified. Is it possible for this code to output the dataset with all several thousand rows, along with the mapping updates to the specified strings?